# Username's skype status is showing "Presence unknown" on a site collection, while it is working well on the other site collections

Tags: user-profile, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, user, user-accounts

I have the following problem, inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013, which we did **NOT** configure any user profile managed service for it.

1. on our root site collection, i have noted that certain user have his Skype status as "Presence unknown", when i hover over the ModifiedBy & CreatedBy list fields, as follow:-

[image]

2. where inside the Skype popup windows, i can see that the following fields; (username + Send Email link + IM) are showing an old email address for the user as follow `FirstName.A-LastName@ourcomany.com` instead of `FirstName.ALastName@ourcomany` (without `-`). and if i click on the username, and i got redirected to `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=**` page, i can see that the username will have the following old value `FirstName.A-LastName@ourcomany.com` inside the `SIP Address`, while he got the correct value inside the Work Email.

also inside other site collections, the Skype status for the user will be working fine, and if i click on the username, and i got redirected to `/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=***`, the `SIP address` for the user will be empty, but the Skype status will show if the user is active, offline,etc, instead of "Presence unknown"..

Now i think the problem is that inside the root site collection, which we have it as the first site collection, the user's Skype id was wrong (with `-`), and it got added to the root site collection as-is, and after updating the user Skype id, it did not get reflected inside the user info on sharepoint. and since we do not have any user profile sync configured, so currently the Skype status is not reflecting the correct username, inside the root site collection.. 
So my question is how i can update the SIP address for the user or set it as empty inside the root site?? since on another site collection the user's SIP Address is empty, but he got the correct Skype status...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each SiteCollection stores information about users in the hidden [User Information List](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/marj/2016/03/14/what-is-hidden-user-information-userinfo-list-in-sharepoint-20102013-and-how-to-fix-when-it-causes-a-site-collection-to-show-old-user-metadata-properties-in-people-picker-control-or-in-a-person-or/).

Your problem should exist in the `SipAddress` attribute of the user. You can confirm this with the following script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourRootSite
$users = $web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems()
foreach ($user in $users) {
  Write-Host "User: $($user.DisplayName) - SIP-Address: $($user["SipAddress"])"
}
```

Then you can remove all SipAddress attributes with this small modification:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://YourRootSite
$users = $web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems()
foreach ($user in $users) {
  Write-Host "Removing SIP-Address for user $($user.DisplayName)"
  $user["SipAddress"] = ""
  $user.Update()
}
```

You can also modify one user by selecting a single list-item with the `GetItemById(<ListEntryID>)` method instead of `GetItems()`

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply. but if i clear SIP-Address by using $user["SipAddress"] = "" will this fix the issue? now i test this on our test environment, and after clearing the SipAddress, the Skype status is showing the actual user status instead of "Presence unknown"... But before proceeding with this on live,, can manually clearing the SipAddress cause any issue, or drawbacks?

Comment: I cannot tell you fore sure if you have any functions that rely on SipAddress. But even if they do: Wrong data is mostly worse than no data. You can alternatively update the SipAddress attribute with the correct value by using $user["SipAddress"] = "Firstname.Lastname@company.com"

Comment: the solution I posted below (-o sync -ignoreIsActive 1)  was using the OOTB way to synchronize the data. Not sure why you want to use custom code to fix this issue. Also this solution needs to be run on each Sitecollection to fix it while mine works on the whole farm.

Answer (score 0):

If the data for the user is not correct in only one site, then the UPA->SP profile sync Job is ignoring the user. This is caused by the user being inactive on the site...

You can force the timer job to ignore the inactive flag by using the following command:

STSADM -o Sync -IgnoreIsActive 1

After this you need to wait a while and make sure to set it back the next day (0 as parameter instead of 1) If you are in a "smaller" company leave it on 1 (less than 10000 users) since the performance hit is not that grave and it also fixes issues with inactive users getting married or having other data changed in their profile.

You could also trigger the timer job and turn it off afterwards. I think the default is to run **once an hour** 
The timer job for SP2013 is:

User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint full synchronization

Comment: as i mentioned before at this stage i am not planning to run any user profile sync, as i need to verify things first before running this, and if user profile sync will have negative impact on our sites.. my question is about having a quick fix for the lync username inside sharepoint site..thanks

Comment: This is NOT a user profile sync... It is a timer job that is syncing from the UPA -> SP ContentDB's. Depending on your farm size the job will only take a few minutes with that flag on.

Answer (score -1):

Try to go to Central Administration->Manage service applications->user profile service application, start a full synchronization to update the User Profiles.

Besides, here are some similar post for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/2813701/lync-presence-is-unavailable-or-missing-in-sharepoint-sites

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/d058b531-76e6-4b60-a35b-7e32a219542e/skype-for-business-presence-unknown-in-internet-explorer-sharepoint-but-when-ie-run-as?forum=sfbfr

Comment: @Sreej as i mentioned before at this stage i am not planning to run any user profile sync, as i need to verify things first before running this, and if user profile sync will have negative impact on our sites.. my question is about having a quick fix for the lync username inside sharepoint site..thanks

Comment: also the 2 links you provided are not related directly to my case.. as i already have lync client application running, and this problem is happening to only 2 users. also this will happen on IE regardless if it is running as admin or not.. the 2 links is describing a problem about integration between lync and sharepoint,, while my problem is regarding user info inside sharepoint..